# Check in ngOnInit if the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Dear I have the following scenario. I have some checks on one screen, when I select some they go to another screen, only the ones I selected for another screen. It stays there on the other screen selected right. The problem that when using the button on this screen is as if it is not selected for something. They only work if I click on them again. Does anyone know how I capture the information that they are selected so I can put no methods? Or... It's done ngFor doesn't have Id , as I present them without being marked, so the user would have to mark it and the method would be invoked

Comment: Hi, can you explain us how are you passing data between screens in order to achieve what you're doing ? In other words. How are you doing to get the checkboxes list on the other screen ?

Answer (score 0):

**component.html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" >
  <p><b>Reactive Checkbox</b></p>

   <ul formArrayName="fruits">

     <li [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let item of form.controls?.fruits?.controls; let i = index">
       <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" />  {{fruits[i].name}}
     </li>

    </ul>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
fruits:Array<any> = [
   { name: '', checked: true },
   { name: '', checked: false }
]

ngOnInit(): void {
  // build reactive form skeleton
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    // control for Checkbox exemple
    fruits: new FormArray([]),
  });
  // bind existing value to form control
  this._patchValues();
}

private _patchValues(): void {
  // get array control
  const formArray = this.form.get('fruits') as FormArray;
  // loop for each existing value
  this.fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
    // add new control to FormArray
    formArray.push(
      // here the new FormControl with item value from fruits
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(fruit.name),
        checked: new FormControl(fruit.checked),
      })
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning in Angular. But I solved my problems using @Output and EventEmitter. Sorry for I wasn't be clarity.